# Why does this keyboard-reading program never detect a start condition?

Tags: c, keyboard, microcontroller, pic, xc8

Programming with MPLAB X IDE v5.40, compiler XC8 v2.30. This uses a PICkit 4 ICSP to program a PIC18F47Q10 device configured to take the following inputs:

- CLK and DATA line from PS/2 female connector.
- Button input which is just lighting an LED when it's pressed to show
  the routine is working

The PS/2 protocol has idle state with CLK and DATA lines high, and that is what's observed - they're polled in the while(1) loop and sent to LEDs to check. The keyboard has been tested and it works. So why doesn't this program ever enter the readRoutine? It should be waiting for a confidence counter to exceed a threshold when it detects the start condition for long enough (CLK low, DATA low).

In debugging mode I can see that it does get some reads of low & low, but it never holds long enough. The oscillator is HFINTOSC at 64MHz so it should definitely be able to read more than 5 instances of low & low. The confidence counter's threshold is set so that I can try different values and see what works. It only enters the routine when it's as low as 5 instances, and it will enter when no key is pressed, so that's just noise. Any higher and it just won't enter, but the keyboard works so what gives?

When a PS/2 key is pressed, the devices drives both lines low before the CLK starts pulsing and DATA is valid to be read on the low pulses. I have tested the routine when it's arranged with logic switches so I'm testing a word, flipping a switch to pulse the clock. It builds the word from LSB to MSB and checks the parity properly the way I'm expecting. But when the keyboard is plugged in I just can't get it to enter the routine and I'm pretty stumped... I will greatly appreciate any help anyone can offer.

By the way, this is not for a class even though it's a common project. Actually I did it in school but of course I had GTAs to help then.

```c
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"

#define PUSHED              1
#define NOT_PUSHED          0
#define WAIT_FOR_CLK_HI     while(!CLOCK_PORT)
#define WAIT_FOR_CLK_LO     while(CLOCK_PORT)
void strobe(void);
void assignLight(void);
void waitForCLK_HI(void);
void waitForCLK_LO(void);
void checkKeyboard(void);
void checkButtonS2(void);
void clearAndBlink(void);
void checkStartCondition(void);
void clockConfidence(void);
uint8_t readRoutine(void);
bool    dataIsValid     = true;
bool    confident       = false;
bool    startCond       = false;
long confidence         = 0;
long confLimit          = 10;
uint8_t byteBuild       = 0x00;
uint8_t zeroBits        = 0;
uint8_t scanCode        = 0;
uint8_t parityBit       = 0;
uint8_t newScan         = 0;
uint8_t lastScan        = 0;
uint8_t currClock       = 0;
uint8_t currData        = 0;
uint8_t wordCount       = 0;
uint8_t switch2Flag     = 0;
uint8_t btn2State       = 0;
long    startConf       = 0;
long    counter         = 0;

void main(void)
{
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    while (1)
    {
        strobe();                                       //Light strobes
        checkButtonS2();                                //Check button
        assignLight();                                  //LED on with button
        checkStartCondition();                          //wait for key-press
    }
}

void checkKeyboard(void)                                //Print scan-code
{
    newScan = readRoutine();                            //Read scan code
    if(newScan != lastScan)                             //Make sure it's a new key-press
    {
        if(newScan == 0xF0) L8_SetHigh();               //Turn on L8 if we see break-code
    }
    lastScan = newScan;                                 //Set lastScan - F0 will have to be ignored (break code)
}

uint8_t readRoutine(void)
{
    WAIT_FOR_CLK_LO;                                    //Wait for START bit
    WAIT_FOR_CLK_HI;                                    //Read DATA on low CLK pulse (typical)

    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)                            //Enter the byteBuilding zone
    {
        __delay_us(15);                                 //Poll halfway thru CLK pulse
        if (DATA_PORT)  byteBuild |= 0x01 << i;         //Set the bit if DATA=1
        else            zeroBits++;                     //Count the zeros for PARITY
        WAIT_FOR_CLK_HI;                                //Wait for next bit
        if (i<7)        WAIT_FOR_CLK_LO;                //Wait for CLK to go LOW. After D7, EXIT LOOP
    }
    
    WAIT_FOR_CLK_LO;                                    //PARITY BIT
    
    __delay_us(15);                                     //Poll halfway thru CLK pulse
    parityBit = DATA_PORT;                              //Take the PARITY bit
    
    //PARITY BIT CHECK///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //If odd 0s and parityBit=1, or if even 0s and parityBit=0, data is corrupted
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if((zeroBits%2 && parityBit) || (!(zeroBits%2) && !parityBit))    dataIsValid=false;
    
    WAIT_FOR_CLK_HI;
    WAIT_FOR_CLK_LO;                                    //STOP BIT
    
    __delay_us(15);                                     //Poll halfway thru CLK pulse
    if(!DATA_PORT)      dataIsValid=false;              //STOP bit must be 1
    WAIT_FOR_CLK_HI;
    
    scanCode = byteBuild;                               //Store the completed byte
    clearAndBlink();                                    //Clear variables, blink lights
    return scanCode;                                    //Return the keyboard scanCode
}


void clearAndBlink(void)
{
    byteBuild   = 0;                                    //Clear the byteBuild tool
    zeroBits    = 0;                                    //Clear the zero bits counter
    dataIsValid = true;                                 //Reset dataIsValid for next
    
    L15_SetHigh();
    __delay_ms(250);                                    //Blink L15
    L15_SetLow();
}

void strobe(void)                                       //Strobe L14, showing program is running
{
    counter++;                                          //Increment counter
    if(counter>256000)                                  //Manually set to be close to 1 second by stopwatch
    {
        L14_Toggle();                                   //L14 strobes to show it's running
        counter=0;                                      //Reset counter
    }
}

void checkButtonS2(void)                                //RC3 sets btn2State, switch2Flag
{
    if(btn2State == NOT_PUSHED)                         //We think the button is not pushed
    {                                       
        if (RC3_GetValue() == LOW)                      //See if the button is pushed
        {
            __delay_ms(30);                             //De-bouncing
            if (RC3_GetValue() == LOW)                  //If the button is still pressed          
            {    
                btn2State = PUSHED;                     //Switch on button state
                switch2Flag = HIGH;                     //Raise the flag
            }
        }
    }
    else                                                //We think the button is pushed
    {
        if (RC3_GetValue() == HIGH)                     //If the button is released
        {
            btn2State = NOT_PUSHED;                     //Set the button state
        }
    }  
}

void assignLight(void)                                  //L13 on when RC3 pressed down
{
    if (switch2Flag)                                    //If the switch has been pressed
    {
        switch2Flag=LOW;                                //Lower the flag
    }                                                   //Add any other actions if desired   
    if(btn2State == PUSHED)  L13_SetHigh();             //L13 ON
        else  L13_SetLow();                             //L13 OFF
}

void checkStartCondition(void)
{
    if(CLOCK_PORT)          L12_SetHigh();              //Display CLOCK
    else                    L12_SetLow();
    
    if(DATA_PORT)           L11_SetHigh();              //Display DATA
    else                    L11_SetLow();
    
    if(!CLOCK_PORT && !DATA_PORT)   
    {
        L0_SetHigh();                                   //LED 0 INDICATOR
        checkKeyboard();                                //Begin when confident of START condition
    }
}

void waitForCLK_HI(void)                                //DEBUG ONLY: Uses confidence to confirm LO-HI transition
{
    while (!confident)                                  //Wait for CLK to go HIGH
    {
        if(CLOCK_PORT)                                  //If CLK is HIGH
        {
            confidence++;                               //Building confidence
            if(confidence>confLimit)        
            {
                confidence  = 0;                        //Clear confidence counter
                confident   = true;                     //Assured of state change
            }
        }   
        else    confidence = 0;                         //Reset confidence
    }           confident = false;                      //Reset for next check
}

void waitForCLK_LO(void)                                //DEBUG ONLY: Uses confidence to confirm HI-LO transition
{
    while (!confident)                                  //Wait for CLK to go LOW
    {
        if(!CLOCK_PORT)                                 //If CLK is LOW
        {
            confidence++;                               //Building confidence
            if(confidence>confLimit)            
            {
                confidence  = 0;                        //Clear confidence counter
                confident   = true;                     //Assured of state change
            }
        }   else    confidence = 0;                     //Reset confidence
    }               confident = false;                  //Reset for next check
}

void clockConfidence(void)                              //DEBUG ONLY: Uses confidence to confirm START condition
{                                                       //When using this for debug, must revise to check for startCond
    if(!currClock && !currData)                         //If CLK&DATA both LOW - Possible START Condition
    {
        startConf++;                                    //Build Start Confidence
        if (startConf > confLimit)                      //Need to hold condition past confLimit
        {
            startConf = 0;                              //Reset Start Confidence
            startCond = true;                           //Set Start Condition
        }
    }   else startConf = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your source code consistently, it is barely readable.

Comment: @thebusybee Well, I disagree that it was barely readable, but alright I went ahead and improved the formatting and commenting. Edited version is more clean. Note that the confidence build may not be necessary for CLK  / DATA lines, but I don't have an oscilloscope so I added them just because I figured it can't hurt.

Comment: Well, well, now it's better, after I used some decent indentation. Now you might have some insight. BTW, do you really mean `!zeroBits % 2`? Actually it is equivalent to `(!zeroBits) % 2`...

Comment: Hmm well I do mean !(zeroBits%2) in that case. Thanks for noting that, I've changed it. I think my tests must not have included that case because parity check worked but that needs an extra set of parentheses. I have a simplified version of the code which I will edit the OP with. The only difference is I'm not using the routine waitForCLK_HI() or any other with confidence counter. I needed this for testing with logic switches that bounce but not with this code so it will be easier to read. Currently its streaming 0xAA scanCode = 0b10101010. So this seems like a big clue which I'm working thru.